# Railscasts 168 - Feedjira Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, rss, railscasts, feedjira

I'm trying to make a RoR app that parses an RSS feed then digs through it for keywords. To add RSS I'm following this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/168-feed-parsing

And it's not working. I've installed the gem and rebooted the rails server. The config/environment line prevents rake db:migrate from working, giving this error:

```
/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)
```

so I left it out.

The FeedEntry console line, in which I pass the url, gives this error: `FeedEntry.update_from_feed("feed://seekingalpha.com/market_currents.xml")
NameError: uninitialized constant FeedEntry::Feedzirra`

And the view code gives this error: `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` with this in the extracted source:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="seeking_alpha">
<h3>Seeking Alpha Feed</h3>
<ul class="list-group">
<% for entry in FeedEntry.all(:limit => 10, :order => "published_at desc") %>
  <li class="list-group-item"><%= link_to h(entry.title), entry.url %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Can you help me fix the problems here? Other than being a complete Rails n00b, I'm guessing my problem is that Feedjira isn't initialized, possibly caused by leaving that line out due to using a newer version of Rails (4.0) and Ruby (2.1.1) than the tutorial does. And perhaps the .xml file format on the feed is also causing a problem. It seems like Feedjira just doesn't want to exist outside of its own model. Any ideas would be very appreciated.

Comment: Also, just checked - Feedjira is working on a local .xml file through the rails console in my app.

Answer (score 0):

All of your errors stem from omitting that first configuration statement.

If you look at the source code from the Railscast, Ryan defines `config` like this in environment.rb:

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
```

Though we can't see your environment.rb, your error states you have not defined `config`.

Without `config`, you can't run migrations, so no `FeedEntry` model, hence the errors in your console script and your view. You will also need that statement to use `Feedzirra::Feed` in your model-- it has to work.

To recap:

- Define `config` in config/environment.rb
- Run your migration
- Compare with the Railscast source code if you get stuck

Also, this Railscast is old (2009); 'Feedzirra' has been renamed 'Feedjira' and you can add it to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'feedjira'
```

You'll have to look at the docs (http://feedjira.com) for any changed functionality in the gem, but that's probably going to be an easier path.

Good luck!